# Keep Getting Error While Trying to Create Fargate Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I've been trying to create a EKS fargate profile on my account, but I keep getting this message:

Misconfigured PodExecutionRole Trust Policy; Please add the eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com Service Principal

What's strange is that I'm doing this in the web console and from what I read the roles I'm being shown are only roles with that service principle. I've verified that the roles have that service principle too. Still anytime I try to create the profile, I get that message. Any ideas on what could actually be causing that?

The execution role policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what's going on, but I found out that this issue only occurs on my account in us-west-1 and us-west-2 for some reason.

Comment: Because the roles are (if not used * in definition), region specific.